# How to import a CSV with a TIME column on SSMS (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssms, bulkinsert

I have a CSV with the following format

```
  COL1     |   COL2
 20211002  |  163136
(YYYYMMDD) | (HHMMSS)
```

On SQL I am creating a table with the following format

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[table] (
    [COL1] DATE,
    [COL2] TIME,
);
```

BULK LOAD:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.[table]
FROM 'path\df_2.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW=2, MAXERRORS=0, FIELDTERMINATOR=',' , ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

The COL1 is working perfectly and being read, however COL02 is giving me trouble and giving me the following error

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 13 (COL2).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the exact bulk load statement that you're using.

Comment: @squillman Done

Comment: Just to be sure, your example file is pipe delimited.  That is just for the sake of formatting in the question, and your file is indeed comma delimited, yes?

Comment: @squillman Yes, I have other .csv that I am loading and they all work perfectly fine with those delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `COL2` data does not adhere to the t-sql `TIME` format of `hh:mm:ss`.  If you are unable to redo your source file to get that column into the proper format you can transform the data during load with `OPENROWSET`, instead of using `BULK LOAD`.

First create a format file like this (name it fmt.xml or whatever):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="COL1" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="COL2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Then use this to bulk load your data:

```
INSERT dbo.[table] (COL1, COL2)
SELECT
    COL1,
    CONCAT(LEFT(COL2,2), ':', SUBSTRING(COL2, 3, 2),':', SUBSTRING(COL2, 5, 2)) COL2
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    BULK 'path\df_2.csv',
    CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMATFILE = 'path\fmt.xml' --the path to your format file from above
) AS csv;
```

The trick here is that `OPENROWSET` reads your data for `COL2` into memory as a `VARCHAR` during the bulk load, as specified in the format file.  Then you can manipulate it using plain t-sql, converting it into a compatible format for `TIME` as you insert the data from memory into your table.

Assuming your `COL2` data is 6 characters in all situations that should do it for you.  If your data is NOT 6 characters in places you'll need to account for that in the `SELECT`;

Comment: Thank you, I ended doing the same with Python for the Col2 and importing to SQL. Works as it should now